# Why won't DB2 use my MQT table?

Tags: sql, db2, database

I've created a user-maintained MQT (Materialized Query Table) in DB2 9.7 (not yet fixpack 1).  It's a simple grouping of the main fact table.  But my queries aren't being rewritten to hit it.

Here's what I've tried:

- Created the MQT with ENABLE QUERY OPTIMIZATION and MAINTAINED BY USER characteristics
- Also included REFRESH DEFERRED & DATA INITIALLY DEFERRED. (Maybe I shouldn't have?)
- Set registry variables telling DB2 to use all types of MQTs for optimization
- Ran "SET INTEGRITY for tableX ALL IMMEDIATE UNCHECKED"
- Ran runstats
- Flushed the cache: FLUSH PACKAGE CACHE DYNAMIC
- Ensured that default query optimization class was at least at level 2 (it's at 5)
- Set default refresh age to 0 (tho I assume this doesn't matter with user-defined MQTs)

Then tried to determine if the optimizer would use the MQT:

- Tried various simple queries that I expect to use the MQT - either:

  - SELECT COUNT(*) FROM fact_table
  - or SELECT group-dimension, COUNT(*) FROM fact_table GROUP BY group-dimension.
- Explain (using db2expln) only referenced the fact table and not the MQT
- Query results showed counts consistent with the fact table and not MQT table
- Query duration was consistent with fact table and not MQT table.

Any suggestions on either a simpler way to tell if a query is using an MQT or what I should try next to get it to use it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

2 things:

1) What is the `CURRENT MAINTAINED TABLE TYPES FOR OPTIMIZATION` register set to?  It defaults to whatever the `DFT_MTTB_TYPES` database configuration parameter is -- and the default value is 'SYSTEM' - so the optimizer would ignore your MQT.

2) Also, your assumption about `DFT_REFRESH_AGE` and MAINTAINED BY USER MQTs is wrong.  `DFT_REFRESH_AGE` still applies -- for a user-maintained MQT, the `CURRENT REFRESH AGE` register must be set to ANY in order for a refresh deferred MQT to be considered.

Comment: 1) Good tip: DFT_MTTB_TYPES was set to SYSTEM.  I've changed that and "CURRENT MAINTAINED TABLE TYPES FOR OPTIMIZATION" both to USER.  Still no effect.

2)  Thanks also here.  I've got both defined as any or  99999999999999.  It was at 0.

However, I've recycled the database, flushed the cache - and am still not hitting the MQT.  Any other thoughts?

Comment: Between my question, your answer and my first comment anyone can see that there are a number of factors here.  At the time of my first comment the database was not using the MQT - but now it is.  The only difference is that a colleague repeated some of my steps.  Maybe I had defined USER with a trailing space (unlikely).  In any event - it is now working.  Queries that were taking 20 seconds are now running in 0.5.  Thanks for the tips.

Answer (score 0):

To debug the issue prepend the query with:

```
EXPLAIN PLAN FOR
```

and run it, then retrieve the diagnostic messages:

```
SELECT EXPLAIN_TIME, DIAGNOSTIC_ID, MSG
    FROM TABLE(EXPLAIN_GET_MSGS(
      CAST(NULL AS VARCHAR(128)),
      CAST(NULL AS TIMESTAMP),
      CAST(NULL AS VARCHAR(128)),
      CAST(NULL AS VARCHAR(128)),
      CAST(NULL AS VARCHAR(64)),
      CAST(NULL AS CHAR(1)),
      CAST(NULL AS INTEGER),
      CAST(NULL AS INTEGER),
      'en_US'))
    AS REGISTRYINFO
    WHERE EXPLAIN_TIME >= (CURRENT TIMESTAMP - 1 HOUR)
    ORDER BY EXPLAIN_TIME desc
;
```

In my case it was:

```
EXPLAIN_TIME              DIAGNOSTIC_ID MSG                                                                                                                                                                                                                
------------------------- ------------- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2015-07-08 10:48:50.940231 1             EXP0053W  The materialized query table "DB2INST1"."XFACETATTR" was not considered for query matching because the isolation level of the query is higher than the isolation level of the materialized query table.
```